# Is it normal behavior for processor speed to quickly throttle, ignoring PL1/PL0 constraint power limits?

Tags: intel, cpu, cpu-load, cpufreq

I recently got a Gigabyte Areo 17 i9-12900hk, and have put Ubuntu 22.04 kernel 5.19 on it.  I ran s-tui to run it through a quick stress-test and found some odd processor behavior that does not happen in Windows.

Behavior in s-tui: For the first 5-10 seconds, the stress-test runs just fine.  Power consumption is in line with power level constraint 1.  Constraint 1 is only set to a timer of 3 seconds, but it will run at this power level for about 10 seconds.  Then speeds drop and power consumption drops to approx 45w on the core and stays there.  Powercap-info shows that constraint 0 (long-term) is set for more than 30 seconds at 70w, so it is clearly ignoring the constraint settings.

According to both s-tui and turbostat, my cpu temps were not too high (maxing at 79c), so I do not think this was thermal throttling.  Just to make sure, I removed and purged thermald, but that did not fix the issue.

I have used powercap-set to change both constraint 0 and 1 power levels and timings, but unless I set the power levels to below 45w, the power levels will automatically drop back to 45w after about 10s.

I tried to replicate this behavior in Windows 11, but I can run at high power levels for as long as I'd like without any throttling. HWinfo shows 90w consistently over multiple minutes with no thermal issues during cpu stress tests.  Thus, I do not think this is a thermal throttling issue.

Here is the output from powercap-info.  One thing I noticed was that the "max_power_uw" in Constraint 0 matches the power consumption levels seen in s-tui after the power consumption levels drop.

```
powercap-info -p intel-rapl 
enabled: 1
Zone 0
  name: package-0
  enabled: 1
  max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
  Constraint 0
    name: long_term
    power_limit_uw: 70000000
    time_window_us: 31981568
    max_power_uw: 45000000
  Constraint 1
    name: short_term
    power_limit_uw: 110000000
    time_window_us: 2998272
    max_power_uw: 0
  Constraint 2
    name: peak_power
    power_limit_uw: 215000000
    time_window_us: 0
    max_power_uw: 0
  Zone 0:0
    name: core
    enabled: 0
    max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
    Constraint 0
      name: long_term
      power_limit_uw: 0
      time_window_us: 976
  Zone 0:1
    name: uncore
    enabled: 0
    max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
    Constraint 0
      name: long_term
      power_limit_uw: 0
      time_window_us: 976
Zone 1
  name: psys
  enabled: 0
  max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
  Constraint 0
    name: long_term
    power_limit_uw: 0
    time_window_us: 27983872
  Constraint 1
    name: short_term
    power_limit_uw: 0
    time_window_us: 976
```

Here is the output from turbostat.  This shows the initial output and the jump to the stress test.  Then the drop after about 15 seconds to 45w.

```
turbostat version 2022.04.16 - Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
CPUID(0): GenuineIntel 0x20 CPUID levels
CPUID(1): family:model:stepping 0x6:9a:3 (6:154:3) microcode 0x429
CPUID(0x80000000): max_extended_levels: 0x80000008
CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR SMX EIST TM2 TSC MSR ACPI-TM HT TM
CPUID(6): APERF, TURBO, DTS, PTM, HWP, HWPnotify, HWPwindow, HWPepp, HWPpkg, EPB
cpu2: MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE: 0x00850089 (TCC EIST MWAIT PREFETCH TURBO)
CPUID(7): No-SGX
CPUID(0x15): eax_crystal: 2 ebx_tsc: 152 ecx_crystal_hz: 38400000
TSC: 2918 MHz (38400000 Hz * 152 / 2 / 1000000)
CPUID(0x16): base_mhz: 2900 max_mhz: 5000 bus_mhz: 100
cpu2: MSR_MISC_PWR_MGMT: 0x000030c2 (ENable-EIST_Coordination ENable-EPB DISable-OOB)
RAPL: 5825 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 45 Watts
cpu2: MSR_PLATFORM_INFO: 0x804043df1811d00
4 * 100.0 = 400.0 MHz max efficiency frequency
29 * 100.0 = 2900.0 MHz base frequency
cpu2: MSR_IA32_POWER_CTL: 0x0024005b (C1E auto-promotion: ENabled)
cpu2: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x2b2b2b2b2e2e3232
43 * 100.0 = 4300.0 MHz max turbo 8 active cores
43 * 100.0 = 4300.0 MHz max turbo 7 active cores
43 * 100.0 = 4300.0 MHz max turbo 6 active cores
43 * 100.0 = 4300.0 MHz max turbo 5 active cores
46 * 100.0 = 4600.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
46 * 100.0 = 4600.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
50 * 100.0 = 5000.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
50 * 100.0 = 5000.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
cpu2: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_NOMINAL: 0x00000019 (base_ratio=25)
cpu2: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_1: 0x00130118 (PKG_MIN_PWR_LVL1=0 PKG_MAX_PWR_LVL1=0 LVL1_RATIO=19 PKG_TDP_LVL1=280)
cpu2: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_2: 0x001d0208 (PKG_MIN_PWR_LVL2=0 PKG_MAX_PWR_LVL2=0 LVL2_RATIO=29 PKG_TDP_LVL2=520)
cpu2: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_CONTROL: 0x00000000 ( lock=0)
cpu2: MSR_TURBO_ACTIVATION_RATIO: 0x00000018 (MAX_NON_TURBO_RATIO=24 lock=0)
cpu2: MSR_PKG_CST_CONFIG_CONTROL: 0x74008003 (UNdemote-C1, demote-C1, locked, pkg-cstate-limit=3 (pc6))
/dev/cpu_dma_latency: 2000000000 usec (default)
current_driver: intel_idle
current_governor: menu
current_governor_ro: menu
cpu2: POLL: CPUIDLE CORE POLL IDLE
cpu2: C1E: MWAIT 0x01
cpu2: C6: MWAIT 0x20
cpu2: C8: MWAIT 0x40
cpu2: C10: MWAIT 0x60
cpu2: cpufreq driver: intel_pstate
cpu2: cpufreq governor: powersave
cpufreq intel_pstate no_turbo: 0
cpu2: MSR_MISC_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00000000 (L2-Prefetch L2-Prefetch-pair L1-Prefetch L1-IP-Prefetch)
cpu0: MSR_PM_ENABLE: 0x00000001 (HWP)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_CAPABILITIES: 0x0117203f (high 63 guar 32 eff 23 low 1)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_REQUEST: 0x00003f06 (min 6 max 63 des 0 epp 0x0 window 0x0 pkg 0x0)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_REQUEST_PKG: 0x8000ff01 (min 1 max 255 des 0 epp 0x80 window 0x0)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_INTERRUPT: 0x00000001 (EN_Guaranteed_Perf_Change, Dis_Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_STATUS: 0x00000000 (No-Guaranteed_Perf_Change, No-Excursion_Min)
cpu0: EPB: 7 (custom)
cpu0: MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT: 0x000a0e03 (0.125000 Watts, 0.000061 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_INFO: 0x00000168 (45 W TDP, RAPL 0 - 0 W, 0.000000 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x968370001f8230 (UNlocked)
cpu0: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (70.000 Watts, 32.000000 sec, clamp ENabled)
cpu0: PKG Limit #2: ENabled (110.000 Watts, 3.000000* sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_VR_CURRENT_CONFIG: 0x800006b8
cpu0: PKG Limit #4: 215.000000 Watts (locked)
cpu0: MSR_DRAM_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: DRAM Limit: DISabled (0.000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POLICY: 9
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: Cores Limit: DISabled (0.000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POLICY: 13
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: GFX Limit: DISabled (0.000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x8a640000 (100 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_STATUS: 0x883d0800 (39 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_INTERRUPT: 0x02000003 (100 C, 100 C)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC3_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC6_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC7_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC8_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC9_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC10_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
Core    CPU Avg_MHz Busy%   Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz IPC IRQ SMI POLL    C1E C6  C8  C10 POLL%   C1E%    C6% C8% C10%    CPU%c1  CPU%c6  CPU%c7  CoreTmp CoreThr PkgTmp  Totl%C0 Any%C0  GFX%C0  CPUGFX% Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 SYS%LPI PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt PKG_%   RAM_%
-   -   232 6.10    3807    2918    1.13    6570    0   60  1520    204 157 6474    0.00    0.63    0.13    0.13    93.04   2.44    54.19   38.23   66  40  66  96.90   21.16   12.65   5.42    64.93   0.00    0.00    0.00    15.90   10.27   0.37    0.00    0.00    0.00
0   0   220 5.33    4135    2918    0.82    183 0   0   64  1   3   296 0.00    0.50    0.00    0.01    94.19   1.39    0.04    93.24   63  10  66  96.90   21.16   12.65   5.42    64.93   0.00    0.00    0.00    15.90   10.27   0.37    0.00    0.00    0.00
0   1   239 5.62    4260    2918    0.79    192 0   0   6   2   2   104 0.00    0.02    0.04    0.01    94.31   1.10
4   2   260 6.36    4093    2918    0.91    331 0   20  73  3   6   381 0.04    0.34    0.05    0.09    93.21   0.85    0.06    92.73   57  1
4   3   203 4.75    4267    2918    0.79    101 0   0   0   1   0   41  0.00    0.00    0.01    0.00    95.23   2.46
8   4   347 8.46    4107    2918    0.94    530 0   0   100 32  26  944 0.00    0.59    0.45    0.43    90.14   1.71    0.43    89.40   66  40
8   5   208 5.01    4146    2918    0.77    248 0   0   7   0   0   199 0.00    0.40    0.00    0.00    94.61   5.17
12  6   402 9.52    4221    2918    1.24    486 0   0   165 27  24  643 0.00    2.65    0.64    0.59    86.67   4.23    0.69    85.56   64  12
12  7   252 5.78    4368    2918    1.14    160 0   1   6   2   0   73  0.01    0.03    0.05    0.00    94.14   7.97
16  8   293 7.48    3918    2918    0.94    794 0   18  613 59  30  860 0.01    4.18    0.44    0.54    87.47   7.81    0.61    84.10   63  0
16  9   247 6.32    3912    2918    0.83    1177    0   5   151 26  26  719 0.00    0.82    0.24    0.42    92.29   8.97
20  10  317 7.78    4076    2918    1.20    504 0   8   145 21  21  711 0.00    0.80    0.24    0.37    90.90   1.84    0.25    90.13   63  29
20  11  226 5.37    4204    2918    0.84    194 0   0   9   2   1   130 0.00    0.05    0.02    0.00    94.57   4.25
24  12  212 6.60    3203    2918    1.44    308 0   0   19  5   5   439 0.00    0.63    0.06    0.03    92.70   0.53    92.87   0.00    59  0
25  13  179 5.74    3116    2918    1.50    574 0   2   49  7   5   371 0.01    0.71    0.08    0.06    93.45   0.55    93.72   0.00    59  0
26  14  183 5.79    3164    2918    1.50    288 0   0   20  10  5   282 0.00    0.20    0.15    0.07    93.81   0.00    94.24   0.00    59  0
27  15  175 5.36    3270    2918    1.54    86  0   0   1   1   1   43  0.00    0.01    0.02    0.00    94.60   0.00    95.17   0.00    59  0
28  16  177 5.41    3268    2918    1.54    148 0   6   71  2   0   106 0.01    0.49    0.06    0.00    94.03   0.03    94.55   0.00    54  0
29  17  171 5.18    3293    2918    1.55    89  0   0   2   0   0   31  0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    94.78   0.00    95.34   0.00    54  0
30  18  167 5.09    3278    2918    1.54    95  0   0   1   0   2   59  0.00    0.01    0.00    0.04    94.87   0.00    95.43   0.00    54  0
31  19  167 5.06    3294    2918    1.54    82  0   0   18  3   0   42  0.00    0.10    0.11    0.00    94.72   0.00    95.25   0.00    54  0
Core    CPU Avg_MHz Busy%   Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz IPC IRQ SMI POLL    C1E C6  C8  C10 POLL%   C1E%    C6% C8% C10%    CPU%c1  CPU%c6  CPU%c7  CoreTmp CoreThr PkgTmp  Totl%C0 Any%C0  GFX%C0  CPUGFX% Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 SYS%LPI PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt PKG_%   RAM_%
-   -   3843    99.67   3856    2918    1.05    27194   0   0   8   1   1   41  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.10    0.33    0.00    0.00    75  40  73  1408.89 100.63  9.51    9.51    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    109.98  104.23  0.18    0.00    0.00    0.00
0   0   4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.80    1426    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    68  10  73  1408.88 100.63  9.51    9.51    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    109.98  104.22  0.18    0.00    0.00    0.00
0   1   4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.80    1446    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23
4   2   4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.79    1289    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    63  1
4   3   4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.79    1302    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23
8   4   4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.80    1288    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    75  40
8   5   4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.80    1552    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23
12  6   4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.79    1321    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    69  12
12  7   4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.79    1291    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23
16  8   4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.82    1453    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    70  0
16  9   4202    97.78   4298    2918    0.81    1954    0   0   8   1   1   41  0.00    0.07    0.01    0.00    1.92    2.22
20  10  4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.81    1265    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    67  29
20  11  4288    99.77   4298    2918    0.82    1339    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23
24  12  3175    99.77   3182    2918    1.55    1302    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    66  0
25  13  3175    99.77   3182    2918    1.55    1275    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    66  0
26  14  3175    99.77   3182    2918    1.55    1271    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    66  0
27  15  3175    99.77   3182    2918    1.55    1332    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    66  0
28  16  3197    99.77   3205    2918    1.55    1272    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    61  0
29  17  3197    99.77   3205    2918    1.55    1265    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    61  0
30  18  3197    99.77   3205    2918    1.55    1275    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    61  0
31  19  3197    99.77   3205    2918    1.55    1276    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    61  0
```

.......

```
Core    CPU Avg_MHz Busy%   Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz IPC IRQ SMI POLL    C1E C6  C8  C10 POLL%   C1E%    C6% C8% C10%    CPU%c1  CPU%c6  CPU%c7  CoreTmp CoreThr PkgTmp  Totl%C0 Any%C0  GFX%C0  CPUGFX% Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 SYS%LPI PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt PKG_%   RAM_%
-   -   2901    99.77   2908    2918    1.06    26656   0   0   0   0   0   1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    59  40  59  1408.88 100.63  5.33    5.33    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    51.80   46.26   0.09    0.00    0.00    0.00
0   0   3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.86    1449    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    56  10  59  1408.88 100.63  5.33    5.33    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    51.80   46.26   0.09    0.00    0.00    0.00
0   1   3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.85    1325    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23
4   2   3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.79    1269    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    51  1
4   3   3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.79    1316    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23
8   4   3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.79    1308    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    59  40
8   5   3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.79    1308    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23
12  6   3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.79    1317    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    57  12
12  7   3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.79    1357    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23
16  8   3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.80    1413    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    55  0
16  9   3188    99.69   3198    2918    0.81    1725    0   0   0   0   0   1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.08    0.31
20  10  3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.79    1285    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    55  29
20  11  3191    99.77   3198    2918    0.80    1407    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23
24  12  2466    99.77   2472    2918    1.55    1296    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    55  0
25  13  2466    99.77   2472    2918    1.55    1254    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    55  0
26  14  2466    99.77   2472    2918    1.55    1301    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    55  0
27  15  2466    99.77   2472    2918    1.55    1256    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    55  0
28  16  2466    99.77   2472    2918    1.55    1271    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    52  0
29  17  2466    99.77   2472    2918    1.55    1260    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    54  0
30  18  2466    99.77   2472    2918    1.55    1272    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    54  0
31  19  2466    99.77   2472    2918    1.55    1267    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    54  0
```

Given that there is no throttling in Windows and that there is plenty of room thermally, I'm hoping that you can come up with some ideas.

As a note, I am an intermediate beginner with Linux, but am willing to try whatever is necessary :).

Thanks so much for reading all of this!